# Ajuda técnica. Agrupamento de sites e melhoramento de tráfego

Tags: php, google, seo

Estou com uma dúvida um pouco técnica, onde não tenho ciência para saber qual decisão tomar, por isso venho pedir ajuda na decisão.

É ela:

Tenho vários sistemas, cada uma com seus domínios:

- sistema1.com.br
- sistema2.com.br
- sistema3.com.br
- ....

e um domínio base, que se refere a empresa que desenvolve.

Pergunta:

É mais vantagem, colocar todos os sistemas em subdomínio dentro do domínio principal?

Ficando assim:

- sistema1.xyz.com.br
- sistema2.xyz.com.br
- sistema3.xyz.com.br

Precisando acessar o painel ai ficaria - sistema1.xyz.com.br/painel.

Essa pergunta é levando em conta a soma de trafego e a relevância que deixará a URL principal mais elegível para o google.

Consegui explicar bem o que estou tentando passar?

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Leia atentamente as dicas a seguir e veja se concorda com a opinião dos autores, *eu particularmente concordo com o segundo argumento quando se trata de performance.*

De acordo com [esse site](https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/dominio-subdominio-subdiretorio/)

Tudo vai depender do seu objetivo.

**Melhorar o posicionamento nas ferramentas de busca**

> Se o foco é melhorar os resultados com busca orgânica, um subdomínio pode não ser
>   a melhor opção, pois o Google considera o subdomínio como um domínio
>   diferente e não como parte do mesmo site. Ou seja, você terá que
>   construir a autoridade do seu subdomínio e isso não gerará resultados
>   para seu domínio principal. Nesse caso, use um subdiretório, pois ele
>   será beneficiado pela autoridade que seu domínio já possuí, o que
>   facilita um bom posicionamento nas páginas de busca.

**SERP Domination**

> Se você já tem uma boa posição na primeira página e seu objetivo é
>   popularizar seu negócio e aumentar o tráfego para seu site, você deve
>   criar um subdomínio. Você basicamente abre mais portas de entrada de
>   visitantes para o conteúdo do seu site, aumentando as chances de
>   atingir a SERP Domination.
>
> SERP Domination é conquistar vários links na primeira páginas dos
>   mecanismos de busca e não ter apenas um link bem posicionado. Com um
>   trabalho de SEO diferenciado para seu domínio e subdomínio, você pode
>   ter mais links apontando para seu site nas primeiras páginas, mesmo
>   para termos mais específicos.
>
> Por exemplo, os resultados de pesquisa no Google para a palavra-chave
>   “Inbound Marketing para empresas tradicionais” mostram o domínio da
>   Resultados Digitais e o subdomínio para agências,
>   agenciasderesultados.resultadosdigitais.com.br.

De acordo com [esse outro site](https://configr.com/blog/como-subdominios-podem-aumentar-a-performance-da-sua-agencia/)

**Os benefícios dos subdomínios para a performance**

> Como podemos ver ao analisar a anatomia do domínio, quando criamos um
>   subdomínio acabamos “criando um novo site” dentro do nosso domínio
>   principal.
>
> Isso oferece mais organização para a sua agência, podendo alocar
>   melhor as diferentes aplicações do seu site e facilitar o acesso dos
>   seus clientes.

**Diferenciação pelos mecanismos de busca e SEO**

> Subdomínios são vistos pelos mecanismos de busca como sites diferentes do domínio principal.
>   A princípio isso pode parecer ruim para SEO, né?
>   No entanto, isso abre diversas oportunidades, como a segmentação!
>   Assim, você poderá ter diferentes sites de segmentos sob um mesmo
>   domínio principal e, com os subdomínios, separar suas autoridades
>   conforme o segmento desejado. Essa separação de “autoridade” para cada
>   subdomínio é uma boa oportunidade para agências que trabalham com
>   blogs ou sites de nichos diferentes. Com isso, essas agências podem
>   efetuar trabalhos de otimização para mecanismos de busca (SEO)
>   diferentes para cada subdomínio e para o domínio principal.

**Na prática**

> A Google possui o mecanismo de busca mais utilizado no mundo,
>   contando com diversas aplicações, como o Google Docs e o Google
>   Adwords. Seguindo as boas práticas de segurança, performance e
>   otimização, ela também separa suas aplicações utilizando subdomínios.
>
> Mecanismo de Busca: google.com
>
> Google Docs: docs.google.com
>
> Google Adwords: adwords.google.com